# How to scan a column to get a new column in Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Pyspark DataFrame with two column: sendtime and charge_state , if charge_state change from "off" to "on", a new charge cycle starts.

Now I want to tags each charge-cycle to give me the output.

**Input:**

```
+-------------------+------------+
|           sendtime|charge_state|
+-------------------+------------+
|2018-03-02 08:00:00|          on|
...
|2018-03-02 09:42:32|          on|
|2018-03-02 09:42:33|          on|
|2018-03-02 09:42:34|          on|
|2018-03-02 09:42:35|         off|
|2018-03-02 09:42:36|         off|
...
|2018-03-02 10:11:12|         off|
|2018-03-02 10:11:13|          on|
|2018-03-02 10:11:14|          on|
...
```

**Output:**

```
+-------------------+------------+---------------+
|           sendtime|charge_state|charge_cycle_ID|
+-------------------+------------+---------------+
|2018-03-02 08:00:00|          on|             c1|
...
|2018-03-02 09:42:32|          on|             c1|
|2018-03-02 09:42:33|          on|             c1|
|2018-03-02 09:42:34|          on|             c1|
|2018-03-02 09:42:35|         off|             c1|
|2018-03-02 09:42:36|         off|             c1|
...
|2018-03-02 10:11:12|         off|             c1|
|2018-03-02 10:11:13|          on|             c2|
|2018-03-02 10:11:14|          on|             c2|
...
```

Comment: your requirement suggests that data has to be processed on one executor which is efficient

Comment: but it can not fit into any individual node of the cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Window functions to perform this task :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df.withColumn(
    'charge_state_lag', 
    F.lag('charge_state').over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('sendtime'))
).withColumn(
    'fg', 
    F.when((F.col("charge_state")=="on")&(F.col("charge_state_lag")=="off"),1).otherwise(0)
).select(
    'sendtime',
    'charge_state',
    F.concat(
        F.lit('C'),
        (F.sum('fg').over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('sendtime'))+1).cast('string')
    ).alias("charge_cycle_ID")
).show()
```

Comment: Window functions are a good way to solve it, many thanks to Steven! My scenario is more complicated than this, I will give it a try then come back

Comment: @Mr.Young How is this solution ? If it works, think about accepting the answer

Comment: It works! window function is the only way to this task on DataFrame. I am thinking about fitting the data to streaming, cus my calculation is hard to express by only window functions

Comment: if the downvoter could say what's wrong ... that'd be helpful

Comment: if fine, because of my very very low reputation